# Magento 2 - Event dispatched when a user clicks "Go To Checkout"

Tags: php, magento, magento2

What is the name of the event that is dispatched when a customer clicks "Go To Checkout" after adding stuff on their cart? I want to register that a user started a checkout process for analytics. Specifically, I need to capture the contents of the cart and other information such as total price etc.

I've tried most of the events on [this list](http://cyrillschumacher.com/magento2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/) that are related to either "checkout" or "cart". None of them seem to be dispatched when a user clicks checkout. The nearest that I could get was

`controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index`

which is dispatched when a user clicks "View and Edit Cart".

I'm looking at a couple of ways to solve this

1. Get the name of the event that is dispatched when a user clicks "Go To Checkout". Observe that event and "hook" my code to it.
2. Or is there a way to see all the events that are being dispatched in real time? I'm thinking that I might be able to find some other event that is dispatched near the same time as checkout and then observe that one.

Answer (score 4):

Use `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **checkout_cart_save_before** this event which you can find in 
**vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Cart.php**

Search following code snippet:

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('checkout_cart_save_before', ['cart' => $this]);
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Probably, this is a second way you are looking for. You can log all events in "\Magento\Framework\Event\Manager::dispatch" method (file ./vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php):

```
public function dispatch($eventName, array $data = [])
{
    $obm = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    /** @var  $logger \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface */
    $logger = $obm->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class);
    $logger->debug($eventName);
    // original code
    $eventName = mb_strtolower($eventName);
    ...
}
```

Log files are placed in "./var/log" folder

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
    sales_quote_save_after
```

Hope, it helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

If I want to log all events that are dispatched after some certain interaction, I go to `Magento\Framework\Event\Manager` and set a breakpoint in the `dispatch` method that logs `$eventName` to the console.

You can also add a log statement or write a plugin in a custom module that logs the event name to some file.

There are many events dispatched when you click `Go to checkout`, maybe `checkout_cart_save_before` is the one you are looking for.

Comment: Modify core inadmissible in Magento, please do not teach like that even saying that is a dirty hack

Answer (score 0):

use layout_render_before_checkout_index_index or controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index